# Magento 2.3 Force Shipping for Downloadable Products

Tags: magento2.3, shipping, simple-product, downloadable

Here is my problem:

I have some books products, and they can be sold digital or printed. But if the customer buys the printed version they MUST get the digital content too.

How can I get that?

I try creating a bundle, with 2 downloadable products, but in that case, I don't get the shipment or a downloadable and simple that in that case, I lost the logic of the link.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain two sets of products. One physical one downloadable. Same information different SKU

Look into a buy x get x free extension

Then if you buy the physical simple product you get the additional digital product free

That should be enough to get shipping and download link in account area

You will need a seperate rule for each physical product